# React Jsx set checked state to false (reset button)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks, use-effect

Here I'm trying to reset selected radio buttons on this list,
however it doesn't work because
I previously change input check from `{checked}` to `{user.checked}`. Refer from `UserListElement.tsx` below

Therefore, I tried the following two methods.

1. in useEffect(), set user.userId = false

```js
useEffect(() => {
    user.checked = false;
  }, [isReset, user]);
```

→ no change.

2. `setChecked` to `true` when addedUserIds includes user.userId

```js
 if (addedUserIds.includes(`${user.userId}`)) {
    setChecked(true);
  }
```

→ Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Any suggestion on how to make this this work?

**UserListElement.tsx**

```js
export const UserListElement = ({
  user,
  handleOnMemberClicked,
  isReset,
}: {
  user: UserEntity;
  handleOnMemberClicked: (checked: boolean, userId: string | null) => void;
  isReset: boolean;
}) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(user.checked);
  const addedUserIds = addedUserList.map((item) => item.userId) || [];

  const handleOnChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const checkedState = e.target.checked;
    setChecked(checkedState); //not called
    user.checked = checkedState;
    handleOnMemberClicked(checkedState, user.userId);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    setChecked(false);
  }, [isReset, user]);

  if (addedUserIds.includes(`${user.userId}`)) {
    user.checked = true;
    // setChecked(true) cause runtime error (infinite loop)
  }

  return (
    <li>
      <label className={style.checkboxLabel}>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          className={style.checkboxCircle}
          checked={user.checked}
          // checked={checked}
          onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)}
        />
        <span>{user.name}</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  );
};
```

**UserList.tsx**

```js
export const UserList = (props: {
    showsUserList: boolean;handleClose: () => void;corporationId: string;currentUserId: string;samePerson: boolean;twj: string;
  }) => {
    const [isReset, setReset] = useState(false);
    .......
    const resetAll = () => {
      setReset(!isReset);
      setCount((addedUserList.length = 0));
      setAddedUserList([]);
      setUserName('');
    };
    ......
    return ( <
      > < div > xxxxx <
      ul className = {
        `option-module-list no-list option-module-list-member ${style.personListMember}`
      } > {searchedUserList.map((user, i) => ( 
      <UserListElement user = { user }
          handleOnMemberClicked = { handleOnMemberClicked }
          isReset = { isReset }
          key = {i} />
        )) }
        </ul> 
      /div>
    <a className="is-secondary reservation-popup-filter-reset" onClick={resetAll}>
      .....
    }
```

**UseAddUserList.tsx**

```
export class UserDetail {
  constructor(public userId: string | null, public name: string | null) {}
}

export let addedUserList: UserDetail[] = [];
export let setAddedUserList: Dispatch<SetStateAction<UserDetail[]>>;

export const useAddUserList = (idList: UserDetail[]) => {
  [addedUserList, setAddedUserList] = useState(idList);
};
```

**Further Clarification:**

Default view

[image]

Searched option (showed filtered list)

[image]

I use `user.checked` because when using only checked, the checked state does not carry on from filtered list view to the full view (ex. when I erase searched word or close the popup).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real answer to this question is that the state should **NOT** be held within your component. The state of checkboxes should be held in `UsersList` and be passed in as a prop.

```
export const UserListElement = ({
  user,
  handleOnMemberClicked,
  isChecked
}: {
  user: UserEntity;
  handleOnMemberClicked: (checked: boolean, userId: string | null) => void;
  isChecked: boolean;
}) => {
   // no complicated logic in here, just render the checkbox according to the `isChecked` prop, and call the handler when clicked
}
```

in users list

```
return searchedUserList.map(user => (
   <UserListElement 
       user={user} 
       key={user.id} 
       isChecked={addedUserIds.includes(user.id)} <-- THIS LINE
       handleOnMemberClicked={handleOnMemberClicked}
    />
)
```

You can see that you almost had this figured out because you were doing this in the child:

```
  if (addedUserIds.includes(`${user.userId}`)) {
    user.checked = true;
    // setChecked(true) cause runtime error (infinite loop)
  }
```

Which indicates to you that the checkdd value is entirely dependent on the state held in the parent, which means there is actually no state to be had in the child.

Also, in React, **NEVER** mutate things (props or state) like - `user.checked = true` - that's a surefire way to leave you with a bug that will cost you a lot of time.

Hopefully this sheds some light

Answer (score -1):

In your `UserListElement.tsx` you are setting state in render, which triggers renders the component again, and again set the state which again triggers re-render and the loop continues. Try to put your condition in the `useEffect` call, also you mutate props, so don't set `user.checked = true`. Instead call  setter from the parent component, where it is defined.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setChecked(false);
  if (addedUserIds.includes(user.userId)) {
    setChecked(true);
  }
}, [user]);
```

Comment: While this may work, it is a common problem in React that people try to synchronize local state when props change. In this case, they should just be using a prop and getting rid of the local state entirely. If you are synchronizing local state and props 0 your component doesn't **own** the data, it's coming from above, and therefore, not state.

Comment: Additionally, `isReset` is not a dependency of this effect.

Comment: @Adam yes correct.